# "None" dimension causes error when using DataSet API Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use Dataset API to feed the resnet found in the latest [Tensorflow official models release](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official).

The basic code is as follows:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("initialized")

    features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(prepared_x.dtype, prepared_x.shape)
    labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=prepared_t.shape)

    dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epoch)

    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

    (next_x_test, next_t_test) = iterator.get_next()
    next_x_test = tf.to_float(next_x_test, name='ToFloat')


    sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: prepared_x,
                                              labels_placeholder: prepared_t})


    print(next_x_test)
    print(next_t_test)

    model = resnet_v2(resnet_size=50, num_classes=num_bins)

    output = model(next_x_test,is_training=True)
```

This last lines throws an error when compiling

> ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be
>   defined. Found `None`.

which makes reference back to the `resent_v2` definition where the final layer is a dense layer.

How can I assert the shape of my features tensor?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tensor.set_shape` to set the shape of a tensor if it happens to be undefined.